# Make Github pages case insensitive?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Is there a way to make github pages case insensitive?

Or in jekyll to ensure all url's are lowercase?

For example this url is valid:

`http://www.example.net/Vegas-2014.html`

but this 404s

`http://www.example.net/vegas-2014.html`

I don't like that from a usability perspective. (think text messaging urls, typing them in, etc.)

I know I can fix this with permalink, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it through configuration of Jekyll or pages or some other technique.

Comment: As a workaround, you could consider using the Jekyll plugin, [jekyll-redirect-from](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from) which has been [whitelisted for GitHub pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-plugins-with-github-pages).

Comment: Joel, thanks for pointing out jekyll-redirect-from is whitelisted. I didn't realize that. It doesn't seem to me it will help in this case as I could use the permalink field to make everything lowercase. I was hoping for a solution to auto-lowercase everything or to make everything case insensitive. From looking at jekyll-redirect it seems I would have to manually add every combo of the casing of letters to achieve a case insensitive appearance.

Comment: Also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48389490/211672

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry but case-sensitiveness is a [standard for URL](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html#htmlurl) that is respected in Unix/Linux world. Windows world in more case insensitive but it's another world ;-).

An Apache, Nginx or other open-source server is case-sensitive by default and can be configured to be case insensitive.

In the Jekyll/Github pages world, we must take care of our cases.

But maybe you can give try to [Jekyll redirect from](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from).

Comment: I realized the problem is with my post filenames. If I make them all lowercase I get the best behavior considering the circumstances - all lowercase so no mixed case.