# How to make github pages url case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, html, github, url-routing, jekyll

Website works for
[jerrygoyal.github.io/Flash-Clipboard](http://jerrygoyal.github.io/Flash-Clipboard)

but not for (404 error):
[jerrygoyal.github.io/flash-clipboard](http://jerrygoyal.github.io/flash-clipboard)
[jerrygoyal.github.io/FLASH-clipboard](http://jerrygoyal.github.io/FLASH-clipboard)
[jerrygoyal.github.io/flaSH-CLIPboard](http://jerrygoyal.github.io/flaSH-CLIPboard)
and so on
You get the idea!
How can I make the url case-insensitive?

I've never worked on `Jekyll` and not sure if my project pages are using `jekyll` or not. I only created an `index.html` page and put inside the `docs` folder of the repository.

I'm using a custom domain (www.jerryfactory.com) to map jerrygoyal.github.io

---

Here's the URL to my Github Organisation site : https://github.com/JerryGoyal/jerrygoyal.github.io

And URL for my Github project site:
https://github.com/JerryGoyal/Flash-Clipboard/tree/master/docs

I'm thinking of moving my project site content to my Github Organisation site if it's possible. So if the URL case insensitivity works for only Organisation site it's fine.

---

Ref: [Org and Project Site in Github](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815954/make-github-pages-case-insensitive

Comment: You could setup redirects for the case sensitivity that you want redirected to the main URL to mimic the behavior you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no direct way to make github page URLs case-sensitive. But, you can use following hack:-

Redirect from 404 page with mixed-case or upper-case URL to lower case URL. Steps to achieve this:-

- Just go to your root repo (your_username.github.io).
- If not already exist then create a `404.html` file and add the following script in it.

```html
<script>
    window.onload = () => {
        currentURL = window.location.href;
        lowerCaseURL = currentURL.toLowerCase();
        if (currentURL != lowerCaseURL) {
            location.replace(lowerCaseURL);
        }
    };
</script>
```

> **Note**:- Make sure your pages/repo name are always in lower-case.

Logic explained with example:-

If your URL is:-

`anmol53.github.io/bmi-tracker`

and someone tried following URL:-

`anmol53.github.io/BMI-Tracker`

By default he/she will get 404. Now we will redirect him/her to `anmol53.github.io/bmi-tracker` by changing case of current URL by using above script.

Comment: ngl that's a sweet hack

Answer (score 17):

> How can I make the url case-insensitive?

The short answer is: **You cannot / It's not possible** in GitHub Pages as of this writing.

---

The long answer is: Having [URLs case-sensitive is a web standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html#htmlurl) and most webservers will respect that. This has nothing to do with Jekyll or any other similar tool. It's a responsibility of the webserver that is serving the HTML pages that were generated by Jekyll, and in the case of GitHub Pages, they use a *nix-based webserver that is compliant with case-sensitive URLs when locating resources.

A common way to solve this problem is to make sure your pages in Jekyll are **always** lower-case, which in turn will generate lower-cased URLs.

This shouldn't really be a problem, unless your users are typing the URLs by themselves... And in that case, if you want to be proactive, you can use the [jekyll-redirect-from plugin](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from) and create redirect entries of the most common ways you believe users will try to access each page.

For example, having the main URL as

- `augustoproiete.github.io/flash-clipboard`

and redirect the ones below to the main one above via [jekyll-redirect-from](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from)

- `augustoproiete.github.io/Flash-Clipboard`
- `augustoproiete.github.io/FLASH-CLIPBOARD`

Comment: as i've mentioned in the question that i've no knowledge about the jekyll. would you mind telling how to do this change?

Comment: @JerryGoyal All the instructions on how to configure it are in the README of the jekyll-redirect-from plugin - https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from

Comment: that README has some installation steps which I don't understand so i followed the steps given in https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/ and it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that redirect-form would work for custom static pages?

Comment: Yep... It works for pages, posts, collection items, etc. If you put a reproducible example on GitHub, I might be able to more easily point out what's missing. BTW, here is an example of a Jekyll site that uses the jekyll-redirect-from plugin and works fine: https://github.com/netponto/netponto.github.io

Comment: this is my organization site for mail URL: https://github.com/JerryGoyal/jerrygoyal.github.io and this is my project site for URL/Flash-Clipboard https://github.com/JerryGoyal/Flash-Clipboard/tree/master/docs

Comment: The redirect plugin will not be able to redirect differently cased URLs, because it faces the same constraint of Github not differentiating between case.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t make it case-sensitive. Sorry. Case-sensitive URLs are a web-standard. It would be cool if URLs were case-insensitive, but that isn’t true.