# Sub-pages on a GitHub pages site

Tags: github-pages

I've just set up a new GitHub Pages page: https://philipnye.github.io/ainfo. I'm not using Jekyll.

My GitHub repo has a `web` folder that itself contains a number of sub-folders, e.g. `web/2044`. Within each is an html file, with a name such as `Abbey-Academies-Trust.html`.

I was expecting to be able to view the relevant page at https://philipnye.github.io/ainfo/web/2044/Abbey-Academies-trust.html, but I'm getting a 404 error.

In that particular folder - `web/2044` - I've also created an `index.html` file, but I'm getting a 404 error for https://philipnye.github.io/ainfo/web/2044/index.html too.

I'm clearly missing something, but I can't see anything in the documentation that suggests why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first url, it's a caps problem on *Trust* : https://philipnye.github.io/ainfo/web/2044/Abbey-Academies-Trust.html.

For the second url everything is ok. The problem was certainly that you have near 2000 pages and that Github page took a while to generate your site.

Comment: In which I learn that URLs are case-sensitive in many cases. Thanks, David. For others who come across this question, it seems like ensuring that URLs are lower case when they're produced is the easiest workaround - or, alternatively, using Jekyll and a Jekyll plug-in that handles redirects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388057/how-to-make-github-pages-url-case-insensitive